Creating a gradient with CILinearGradient
Hello i've been doing some with with CIFilters and I have a basic understanding of many of the basic ones such as hue, brightness etc..
What i'm trying to understand is how to create a linear gradient using CIFilter, below is my attempt but when I put the outImage into an imageview nothing is displaying, what am I doing wrong?

            CIFilter *gradientfilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILinearGradient"];
             [gradientfilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0.75*img.size.height]    forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
             [gradientfilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
             [gradientfilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0.5 *img.size.height] forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
             [gradientfilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
             
             CIFilter *gradientfilter2 = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILinearGradient"];
             [gradientfilter2 setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0.25*img.size.height]   forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
             [gradientfilter2 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
             [gradientfilter2 setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0.5 *img.size.height] forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
             [gradientfilter2 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
             
             CIFilter *compositingFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAdditionCompositing"];
             [compositingFilter setValue:gradientfilter.outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
             [compositingFilter setValue:gradientfilter2.outputImage    forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
            
            outImage  = compositingFilter.outputImage;



Can you please try to crop the image to some fixed size before assigning it to the view? [outputImage imageByCroppingToRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)]

Cropping the image as suggested will also produce output which may be placed in an NSImageView after conversion from a CIImage to an NSImage.

Thank you I will try that when back at my Mac thank you

One way to visualize the output is to draw the CIImage into an NSView.    A CIContext derived from the NSView's NSGraphicsContext is used with this technique. You may run the following source code in Xcode by copy/pasting into the 'main' after deleting pre-existing code and also deleting the pre-supplied AppDelegate files.
Note that I changed the 'vectorWithX:' from zero to 400 on point1 of the first filter.
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <CoreImage/CIImage.h>
#import <CoreImage/CIFilter.h>
#import <CoreImage/CIContext.h>

@interface CustomView : NSView
@end

@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect]) != nil) {
        // Add initialization code here
    }
    return self;
}

-(CIImage *) drawLinearGradient: (CGContextRef) context frame: (CGRect) viewBounds {
    
    CIFilter *gradientfilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILinearGradient"];
    [gradientfilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0.75*400] forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
    [gradientfilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
    [gradientfilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:400 Y:0.5*400] forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
    [gradientfilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
    
    CIFilter *gradientfilter2 = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILinearGradient"];
    [gradientfilter2 setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0.25*400] forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
    [gradientfilter2 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
    [gradientfilter2 setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0.5 *400] forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
    [gradientfilter2 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
    
    CIFilter *compositingFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAdditionCompositing"];
    [compositingFilter setValue:gradientfilter.outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [compositingFilter setValue:gradientfilter2.outputImage forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
    
    CIImage *outImage  = compositingFilter.outputImage;
    NSLog(@"CIImage = %@",outImage);
    CIContext *outputCIContext = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:context options:NULL];
    NSLog (@"outputCIContext = %@",outputCIContext);
    [outputCIContext drawImage:outImage inRect:viewBounds fromRect:CGRectMake(0,0,400,400)];
    return outImage;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] CGContext];
    [self drawLinearGradient:ctx frame:NSRectToCGRect(rect)];
}

-(BOOL)isFlipped {
    return YES;
}
@end


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
}

-(void) buildMenu;
-(void) buildWindow;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void) buildMenu {
    NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
    NSMenuItem *menuBarItem = [NSMenuItem new];
    [menubar addItem:menuBarItem];
    [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
    NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
    NSMenuItem *quitMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit"
                                                          action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
    [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
    [menuBarItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
}

- (void) buildWindow {
#define _wndW  700
#define _wndH  650
    
    window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH )
                                         styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
                                           backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];
    
    [window center];
    [window setTitle: @"Test window"];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
    
    // **** Custom View **** //
    CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 20, 80, _wndW - 40, _wndH - 100 )];
    [[window contentView] addSubview:view];
    
    // ***** Quit btn ***** //
    NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 5, 40, 40 )];
    [quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
    [quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
    [quitBtn setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin];
    [quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
    [[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
}

- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
    [self buildMenu];
    [self buildWindow];
}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
}
@end

int main (){
    NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    [application setDelegate:appDelegate];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [application run];
    return 0;
}


Alternate technique using NSImageView:

Crop the CIImage with the code in the first comment; it's infinite in size initially.
Convert CIImage to NSImage with the following code and insert into NSImageView:

NSCIImageRep *imageRep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:ciImage];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[imageRep size]];
[image addRepresentation:imageRep];
[imageView setImage:image];



Thank you, I will look through the code when i'm at my Mac, appeciate the help - i'm always looking to learn!
